# Autodesk Forge: I created an app to translate CAD files, but cannot see properties for an assembly

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

So I created a nodejs app to translate CAD files and to display them in the viewer. For .rvt files and individual Inventor components I can see the properties by going to Model Browser and clicking on each component, however, I cannot see properties for an entire Inventor assembly. How can I go about seeing assembly properties?

I am using this sample: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-walkthrough-online.viewer

Only change I made was set compressedUrn to true and added a rootFileName to allow Inventor assemblies to be translated.

Comment: Could you please point out what exact properties you cannot find?
Screenshot of the property in Inventor and where you are looking for it in the Viewer?

Comment: I can show you how it's supposed to look in a Viewer on the Autodesk site that uses the same APIs found at this link: https://viewer.autodesk.com/designviews. On the right is the property window I would like to see: https://i.imgur.com/FPXE2mI.png. However, in the app I created, I do not see it because I cannot click on the actual assembly, only on the individual components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option called **modelBrowserExcludeRoot** that you can set to **false** when creating the **Viewer**. In that case, the **root object** of the model will be visible in the **Model browser** and when selecting it you'll see the properties of the assembly in the **Properties** palette
e.g.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
  viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
    document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), 
    { 
      modelBrowserExcludeRoot: false 
    }
  );
  viewer.start();
  var documentId = 'bubble.json'; 
  Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});
```

Also have written a blog post about it just now:
[Root object not visible in Model browser](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/root-object-not-visible-model-browser)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'd also appreciate some help with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096019/autodesk-forge-design-automation-demo-issues