# Autodesk Forge Design Automation demo issues

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to use this web app: https://inventor-config-demo.autodesk.io/

However, when trying to upload an Inventor Assembly (zipped, with .iam in the root and .ipt files in a subfolder called 'components') I get the following error:

> Internal error
>
> Try to repeat your last action and please report the following
> message: Structure needs cleaning

Comment: Would you be able to provide an assembly that we could use to reproduce this issue? And perhaps a screen shot as well of the error popping up?

Comment: Here is an assembly: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-tutorial-postman/blob/master/ModelDerivative_02/tutorial_data/Tuner.zip. Here is the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/P2v1oXp.png. This time I seem to be getting a different error than before.

Comment: And now I'm getting a different error again - a 500 error. Here is the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/xNgnpuV.png

Answer (score 1):

Tested your attached dataset and should be uploaded correctly now.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. However, I cannot see the properties of the assembly. @Adam Nagy helped me with it for my own Viewer app the other day here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080853/autodesk-forge-i-created-an-app-to-translate-cad-files-but-cannot-see-properti. Could you make the root object visible in Model browser for the demo?

Comment: Anyways, thanks for the help, but I would like to add that, unfortunately, this replacement for the Configurator 360 is less useful and its functionality is inferior to what Configurator 360 provided. The Configurator 360 was simple to use and did not require any programming knowledge. I hope in time you will improve this app to match everything that was possible with the Configurator 360.

Comment: This is not replacement of Configurator 360, but intended only as demo tool to show how it can be used.

Comment: Are you considering offering a replacement that's just as useful and just as easy and straightforward to use? It would be very beneficial.